# Configure WCF Client to consume a WCF Service using HTTP GET

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a WCF Service which allows only HTTP GET requests:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string GetAppData()
```

The service is exposed using webHttpBinding

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AppSvcBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <behaviors>
```

I have my client whose config looks like

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/AppService/Service.svc" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfig"
            contract="AppSvc.IService" 
            behaviorConfiguration="AppSvcBehavior"
            name="AppSvcClient">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
    </client>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AppSvcBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My client code is a simple

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient("AppSvcClient");
String result = client.GetAppData();
```

On executing this code I get the error:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.

I checked with fiddler and found that my client is sending a POST message whereas the service expects a GET hence the error.

I wish to know how to configure the client so that is sends GET request to the service.

Comment: What does the rest of your server-side configuration look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use WebGet instead of WebInvoke

**Edit**

Start by changing your method to this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "/")]
public string GetAppData()
```

Make sure that webhttpbinding is specified on the server side.

This fixes it on the server side.

Take a backup of your client code.

On the client side delete the service reference. Make sure that all config is removed.

Then add the service reference again. Now it shoud be OK.

Comment: WebGet is used to specify how the service should behave.

Comment: I need something on the client side to mention the same

Comment: You need to update the web reference after you make the change for the client to update

Comment: for a webHttpBinding, updating service reference is of no use.

Comment: I tried WSHTTPBinding too but no change. I would like to know the the config change in Binding or Behavior which needs to be dont to tell .NET to make the service call a GET request instead of POST.

Comment: When using wshttpbinding you must remove the webget / webinvoke. With wshttpbinding all requests are POST.

Comment: My original problem still remains with WebHttpBinding which allows GET but can not make a WCF client which can use GET

Comment: @sandyiit I have similar problem, how did you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the generated proxy service interface on the client was missing the `WebGet` attribute on my methods.

I added the attribute manually and it resolved the problem.

So it seems like the best current solution is to extract the service interfaces into a separate assembly and then share this assembly between the server and its clients.

The automatic proxy generator seems to be buggy.